# Correct way to add thirdy-party dependencies on a wildfly-swarm ejb-jar deployment

Tags: wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to create a wildfly swarm jar for a ejb-jar deployment that contains only a MDB.

The bean `onMessage` method is using a thirdy party library that's included in the project dependencies.

The generated uber jar contains the library but for some reason I get a `ClassNotFound` exception when I try to use the library.

If we change the packaging type from simple "jar" to "war" everything works as expected.

What is the correct way to add thirdy-party dependency to a simple ejb-jar deployment for wildfly swarm ?

Comment: I guess it would be possible to create a `module.xml` for your third-party library and add the module dependency to the JAR deployment via `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`, or something like that, but why not use a WAR which can actually contain the dependencies in `WEB-INF/lib`? Isn't it just much easier?

Comment: As @Ladicek pointed out, JARs don't have dependencies bundled. So to use a JAR you would need to use module.xml files.

In this case it's just easier to use a WAR where it happens for you

Comment: I just thought it was possible to create an optimized swarm without the web stack that in that case isn't used. Another option would be to use an ".ear" packaging but I'm aware that isn't yet supported. In the meanwhile we're using ".war" packaging as you suggested.

Comment: I have similar problem and I am not able to deal with it. From my point of view if it is repackaged with dependencies using wildfly-swarm-plugin, it just should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the "correct" solution is. It always seemed a bit odd to me that a thorntail package (formerlly wildfly swarm) always needed to be a WAR, and always needed to include `undertow` and/or `jaxrs` even if they were not being used.

As the first comment above aludes, it is posible to include third party dependencies in a JAR package.

Within `src/main/resources` of my maven project I've added the sub directories `modules/com/example/mymodule/main` and I've added `module.xml` inside of the `main` directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.example.mymodule">
<resources>
    <artifact name="org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.13" />
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"></module>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.io"></module>
    <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents"></module>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

The above xml references maven artifacts that I have included in my POM. You can also reference other modules.

I then added a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to `src/main/resources/META-INF`

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.example.mymodule" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Any 3rd party dependency that you add to your POM will now need adding to module.xml. It's a bit of a pain I know, it would be really nice if there was something that the maven plugin could do to automate this.